# In what Michael Jackson tour and in which song did Jackson perform this particular dance sequence? Is there a name for it?

Tags: michael-jackson

There's a unique, short [segue](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segue) in Michael Jackson's performances circa 1996 where the music is quiet and rhythmic and Jackson does a very particular sequence of robotic/mechanical yet as always expressive dance moves. Years ago I had seen a compilation video of this assembled from many performances in many countries and each one is *a bit* different but the music is always about the same as is in the video below.

Is it possible to identify what the name of the tour is or in what song (or between which songs) this takes place?

There are a few versions shown betwen `06:03` and `07:20` in the video [Michael Jackson Dance Evolution 1968 - 2009](https://youtu.be/Zcxby9ntD_E?t=364)

[image: screenshot Michael Jackson Dance Evolution 1968 - 2009] [image: screenshot Michael Jackson Dance Evolution 1968 - 2009]

Several more versions here: [Michael Jackson - Stranger In Moscow Best Dance Moves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDXgSfOz_X8).

Comment: Not enough characters for me to edit myself, but I think you mean _segue._  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segue and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segway.

Comment: Looks like MJ’s take on Pop and Lock.